# How can I make the plus symbol fit on the lowest row?

Tags: css

[calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyCqA.png)

so the plus symbol has to fit on the lowest row so there is 5 buttons, the other rows still have to have only 4 buttons

each row has a class:
`first-row`
`second-row`
`third-row`
`fourth-row`

```
.buttons {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: your grid has 4 rows and 4 cols

Comment: Could you provide a fully working cod example? Its hard to work with only the css.